# Loop Through an excel column and check if each values has a match on another excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 excel files named Recon File and DataExt File.
Both files have a column named PNR.

I need to check whether each value in Pnr column of Recon has a match on Pnr column of DataExt.
If match is found, check how many matches are there.

If 0 match found, Leave the Column H in Recon as Blank

If 1 Match if found Copy values from cells of  D,E,F and G columns corresponding to the matched Pnr Cell to the Recon File in D,E,F,and G.

If 2 Matches are found, Then check whether for the first & Second match the Column named Sector in Recon also matches with the Sector Column in DataExt. If it matches Copy values corresponding to that columns else Copy values to the Return column.

If more than 2 matches found Fill the Recon column as More than 2 matches found.

Can anyone help me with VBA code for excel Macros.

Comment: what did you achieve yet? what is the problem? just use nested loop, and some conditions

Answer (score 1):

jishnu welcome to StackOverflow. Below is a good starting point for what you are looking for. Please review and try to modify to get you where you want.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub Test()

        Dim wbR As Workbook, wbD As Workbook
        Dim wsR As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet
        Dim LastrowR As Long, LastrowD As Long, i As Long, CountTimes As Long
        Dim PNR As String

        Set wbR = Workbooks("Recon.xlsm")
        Set wbD = Workbooks("DataExt.xlsx")

        Set wsR = wbR.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsD = wbD.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Let as assume that PNR column is column A, in Sheet 1, in both workbooks.
        'Also keep in mind that both workbooks should be open and have the following types (Recon -> .xlsm & DataExt ->  .xlsx)

        'Find the last row of PNR column in Recon File
        LastrowR = wsR.Cells(wsR.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Find the last row of PNR column in DataExt File
        LastrowD = wsD.Cells(wsD.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Loop PNR column in Recon File
        For i = 2 To LastrowR
            'Assign value to PNR
            PNR = wsR.Range("A" & i).Value
                'Count how many times PNR appears in column A DataExt file
                CountTimes = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsD.Range("A2:A" & LastrowD), PNR)

                'If appears 1 time
                If CountTimes = 1 Then
                'If appears 2 times
                ElseIf CountTimes = 2 Then
                'If appears more than 2 times
                ElseIf CountTimes > 2 Then
                End If

        Next i

    End Sub
```